# Docker container does not run with a non-root user

Tags: docker

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    apt-utils \
    curl \
    # Install git
    git \
    # Install apache
    apache2 \
    # Install php 7.2
    libapache2-mod-php7.2 \
    php7.2-cli \
    php7.2-json \
    php7.2-curl \
    php7.2-fpm \
    php7.2-gd \
    php7.2-ldap \
    php7.2-mbstring \
    php7.2-mysql \
    php7.2-soap \
    php7.2-sqlite3 \
    php7.2-xml \
    php7.2-zip \
    php7.2-intl \
    php-imagick \
    # Install tools
    openssl \
    nano \
    graphicsmagick \
    imagemagick \
    ghostscript \
    mysql-client \
    iputils-ping \
    locales \
    sqlite3 \
    ca-certificates \
    && apt-get clean && rm -f /var/www/html/index.html && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/**

ENV LANG en_US.utf8

RUN groupadd --gid 5000 newuser \
    && useradd --home-dir /home/newuser --create-home --uid 5000 \
        --gid 5000 --shell /bin/sh --skel /dev/null newuser

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY index.php /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80

HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=3s --retries=3 CMD curl -f http://localhost || exit 1

CMD ["apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]

USER newuser
```

The error I get:

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down AH00015: Unable to open logs Action '-D FOREGROUND' failed. The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action '-D FOREGROUND' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Henry wrote:

> A non root user cannot bind to ports below 1024. Use a port that is higher e.g. 8080.

I suggest you change apache port and, if you need to access apache from the host, map the port 8080 to 80 in docker.

e.g.

```sh
docker build -t myapacheimg .
docker run -it --rm -p 8080:80 myapacheimg
```

In order to have this stuff working you need to perform the following operations:

- change the ports in the /etc/apache2/ports.conf
- change the virtualhost in the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
- change the ownership of the /var/log/apache2 and /var/run/apache2 folders

In other words, here's an excerpt of the Dockerfile:

```
...
    && apt-get clean && rm -f /var/www/html/index.html && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/**

COPY ./ports.conf /etc/apache2/ports.conf
COPY ./000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

ENV LANG en_US.utf8

RUN groupadd --gid 5000 newuser \
    && useradd --home-dir /home/newuser --create-home --uid 5000 \
        --gid 5000 --shell /bin/sh --skel /dev/null newuser

RUN chown -R newuser /var/log/apache2 /var/run/apache2
...
```

ports.conf

```
Listen 8080
```

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

IMHO this is an ugly solution. I'd use the docker image `php:7.2-apache` and avoid all these problems.

Comment: Thank you Stefano, so you'd use php:7.2-apache instead?!  one last question, how to check outside the container if it's running as a root or a different user? there's a command with exec, I forgot how to write it...

Comment: `docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID ps auxwww`

Comment: WoW.. you helped me a lot, thank you so much, Stefano

Comment: I just checked and for obvious reasons, the apache in that container starts as root (it uses port 80) and spawn new processes under a different user (www-data) to perform operations.

Comment: What command you ran to see those apache processes?

Comment: the one I mentioned earlier: `docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID ps auxwww`

Answer (score 0):

A non root user cannot bind to ports below 1024. Use a port that is higher e.g. 8080.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without changing the port also, using the `setcap` command to modify the linux capability.

For example, If you wish to use the default port `80` for `apache2` then your Dockerfile will look something like this:

```
[...]
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libcap2-bin \
    && setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/sbin/apache2  \
    && chown www-data:www-data /var/log/apache2
USER www-data
[...]
```